# Read {Object} String Data from List<object>

Tags: c#, list, object

I have a c# list type with multiple objects within.

The structure would be

```
> -List<object>
> --[0] object{object[]}
> ---[0] = object {string}
> ---[1] = object {string}
> ---[2] = object {string}
> --[1] object{object[]}
> ---[0] = object {string}
> ---[1] = object {string}
> ---[2] = object {string}
```

I can not figure out how to extract the contents of the object strings in each array. No doubt a newbie mistake.

Can anyone give me a pointer please?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly you have a List<object> whose object elements contain arrays of objects whose elements are actually strings. I don't understand why you wouldn't just use List<string[]> and save all the ugly type-wrapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `List<object>` really contains only `object[]` where the elements are `string`.  Try the following

```
List<object> source = ...;
List<string> destination = new List<string>();
foreach (var obj in source) {
  var array = (object[])obj;
  foreach (var str in array) {
    destination.Add((string)str);
  }
}
```

If LINQ is available you can do the following

```
List<string> destination = source
  .SelectMany(x => ((object[])x).Cast<string>())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: how silly of me. Of course its a nested object within an object... so I need two loops. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Object[] record in someList) {
  foreach(Object item in record) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you actually need to use a `List<String[]>`.